# Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit RAM usage

Tags: 64-bit, 12.04, ram

I'm looking forward to download Ubuntu 12.04. But which bit version will fit best on my computer?.

- Intel Pentium 4 3.06 1mb cache LGA,
- Asus p5pe-vm motherboard,
- 1GB Ram (512+512)
- nVidia Geforce 6200 128mb AGP graphics card.

Will I run out of RAM? Or is it good to use 32bit more than using 64 bit on this? This computer fully supports Windows 7 64bit edition and runs better than 32bit.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 10.10 32bit and it runs like a dream (11.10 is much slower on this PC) Please help me before 26th of April!

Comment: There are [P4s that match this description](http://ark.intel.com/products/27462/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-524-supporting-HT-Technology-%281M-Cache-3_06-GHz-533-MHz-FSB%29). I doubt Win7-64 would run without a 64bit processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64bits is the way to go on 12.04, don't think that you having 1Gb of RAM will take any difference from 32bit. Its still very low.

12.04 is definitely a lot fast than 11.10, you will for sure notice the difference, running it in a vbox on my laptop with 764Mb or reserved RAM and its still usable. I cannot say the opposite from 11.10.

You should upgrade to 12.04 since its probably the last LTS that your computer will support, but if you have the chance get some more RAM as soon as you do so. The rest of the hardware you have on that list is supported out of the box and the CPU is fast enough for any task you trow at it.

Comment: Thanks.. so I won't run out of memory.. right? Are there any issues with Apps on 64bit version? i've browsed around and found that some users found flash plugin behaving bad, and some says it is fixed and so on..Thank you for the advice, but DDR1 rams are no longer available. But I don't see any huge difference between this PC and newest i3 Pc running the same ubuntu 10.10 os. This PC won't die yet!(It's my first one, how could I let it die!, I just upgraded it with a new 19" LCD monitor, now I run dual monitors!)

Comment: You will once you have 20 tabs open in Firefox :) Get more RAM _asap_! 64bit support is largely optimized now in 12.04 and remember that the reports you are looking at atm are for beta. Wait until its stable, install 64bit. There should almost no differences between packages and packages installation, 12.04 64bit is the way to go. You will not find much difference between RAM usage in 32bits and 64bits, so go for one that at least uses your CPU the proper way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait for another 24 days and drink 64 bit :-)

Answer (score 3):

The difference in used RAM between 32-bit and 64-bit isn't huge but it does exist.

The bigger change is between the applications used. The difference in memory usage between Gnome Panel and Unity is more noticeable (in my experience) but you can reinstall Gnome Panel or try a lighter desktop like LXDE, XFCE, etc.

Will you run out of RAM? That somewhat depends on your current usage. If you're right on the border of going into swap, yeah that possibility exists. Pair that with modern applications which put less emphasis on saving memory and you might have issues.

I'd strongly consider an upgrade. 2x1GB of DDR400 is about £30 new (cheaper used) and easy to install. Then again, it's old, old, old. You might be better off running this computer into the ground and upgrading the whole thing.

Comment: Yes I accept, It's ooooollllddddd, But who thought this "ant" can run Ubuntu 10.10 like a lightning strike these days!!!. you have to believe me, I tested 10.10 on intel i3 2.*, 4GB ram,1Gb nvidia geforce 8*** machine and what are the results???, this "ant" stood top of that "hippo"(If i7=elephant) you are right, I should throw this away. but I'll continue using it, It's family now (More like a second father to me-It thought me lot of things on it's own)

Comment: Well... Try it. If it's sluggish, consider some more RAM or going back to 10.10 (that will take a reinstall - you can't downgrade like you would upgrade).

Comment: Nope,it is a wubi install(easy to backup and restore when something goes wrong) and 12.04 will be a wubi too